# What could produce this bizzare behavior with two threads sleeping at the same time?

Tags: c, multithreading, opengl

There are two threads. One is an events thread, and another does rendering. The rendering thread uses variables from the events thread. There are mutex locks but they are irrelevant since I noticed the behavior is same even if I remove them completely (for testing).

If I do a sleep() in the rendering thread alone, for 10 milliseconds, the FPS is normally 100.

If I do no sleep at all in the rendering thread and a sleep in the events thread, the rendering thread does not slow down at all.

But, if I do a sleep of 10 milliseconds in the rendering thread and 10 in the events thread, the FPS is not 100, but lower, about 84! (notice it's the same even if mutex locks are removed completely)

(If none of them has sleeps it normally goes high.)

What could produce this behavior?

--

The sleep command used is Sleep() of windows or SDL_Delay() (which probably ends up to Sleep() on windows).

Comment: If you sleep for 10 milliseconds every frame in the rendering thread, but you still achieve 100 fps, then your rendering code is taking zero time!  Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: You need to tell us how many CPU cores are involved. Two threads sleeping 10 on a single CPU will result in a sleep 20 real time. On two CPU cores it should be 10 real time.

Comment: @Zan: Presumably `sleep()` yields to the OS scheduler, so that another thread can step in...

Comment: @Oli: D'oh! I don't know what I was thinking. I guess I was thinking of some kind of busy wait. You are absolutely right, Oli.

Comment: The "100 exactly" point is not important since the app is generally fast, about 1300FPS unsleeped and a sleep of 10 generally approaches almost exactly 100 (the reality is you notice flactuations ~1-2FPS).

Comment: On Windows 2000 (I tested it - and I imagine it's true still, although it might vary by CPU), a Sleep() of less than 13ms oscillates between a 0ms delay and a 13ms delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found an answer (own answer).

Sleeping is not guaranteed to wait for a period, but it will wait **at least** a certain time, due to OS scheduling.

A better approach would be to calculate actual time passed explicitly (and allow execution via that, only if certain time has passed).

Answer (score 0):

The threads run asynchronously unless you synchronise them, and will be scheduled according to the OS's scheduling policy.  I would suggest that the behaviour will at best be non-deterministic  (unless you were running on an RTOS perhaps).

You might do better to have one thread trigger another by some synchronisation mechanism such as a semaphore, then only have one thread Sleep, and the other wait on the semaphore.

I do not know what your "Events" thread does but given its name, perhaps it would be better to wait on the events themselves rather than simply sleep and then poll for events (if that is what it does).  Making the rendering periodic probably makes sense, but waiting on events would be better doing exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior will vary depending on many factors such as the OS version (e.g. Win7 vs. Win XP) and number of cores.  If you have two cores and two threads with no synchronization objects they should run concurrently and Sleep() on one thread should not impact the other (for the most part).

It sounds like you have some other synchronization between the threads because otherwise when you have no sleep at all in your rendering thread you should be running at >100FPS, no?

In case that there is absolutely no synchronization then depending on how much processing happens in the two threads having them both Sleep() may increase the probability of contention for a single core system.  That is if only one thread calls Sleep() it is generally likely to be given the next quanta once it wakes up and assuming it does very little processing, i.e. yields right away, that behavior will continue.  If two threads are calling Sleep() there is some probability they will wake up in the same quanta and if at least one of them needs to do any amount of processing the other will be delayed and the observed frequency will be lower.  This should only apply if there's a single core available to run the two threads on.

If you want to maintain a 100FPS update rate you should keep track of the next scheduled update time and only Sleep for the remaining time.  This will ensure that even if your thread gets bumped by some other thread for a CPU quanta you will be able to keep the rate (assuming there is enough CPU time for all processing).  Something like:

```
DWORD next_frame_time = GetTickCount(); // Milli-seconds. Note the resolution of GetTickCount()
while(1)
{
  next_frame_time += 10; // Time of next frame update in ms
  DWORD wait_for = next_frame_time - GetTickCount(); // How much time remains to next update
  if( wait_for < 11 ) // A simplistic test for the case where we're already too late
  {
    Sleep(wait_for);
  }
// Do periodic processing here
}
```

Depending on the target OS and your accuracy requirements you may want to use a higher resolution time function such as QueryPerformanceCounter().  The code above will not work well on Windows XP where the resolution of GetTickCount() is ~16ms but should work in Win7 - it's mostly to illustrate my point rather than meant to be copied literally in all situations.